# Expected C++ compiler error in yvals_core.h

Tags: c++

I am using CMake with Visual Studio and I keep getting the error `yvals_core.h(23): fatal error C1189: #error:  STL1003: Unexpected compiler, expected C++ compiler.`

This error only happened after I moved all my includes to my precompiled header. It looks like the `__cplusplus` macro is not defined for some reason.

More information: I just have a header file including all the includes I need. Then I just added that header file to the precompiled header by using `target_precompile_headers`

Comment: Precompiled headers are used all the time, so we know that they don't just drop macros. The odds are 99.9% that you accidentally compile one part of the code as C instead of C++.

Comment: @BoP I just looked at the output. looks like the error happens when it was compiling a C object `cmake_pch.c.obj`. That would certainly explain why the `__cplusplus` macro wasn't defined. It looked like it was also compiling a separate C++ object `cmake_pch.cxx.obj`. I think I'm going to try and see which file included the `yvals_core.h`. I will report back as soon as possible

Answer (score 2):

I have recently experienced the same issue.

I noticed that the iostream.h library used for C++ was included in a .c file within my program. Once I removed this include directive (#include <iostream.h>) the error was resolved.

Check all the include directives within the program and verify them for correctness. Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in MS Visual Studio 2022 with a C project that mistakenly included `<iostream>`
Removing this fixed the issue.